# QTableWidget to multiple files

Tags: c++, qt

I’ve got QTableWidget with data like this:
[table.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWFuT.png)
The table can contains only names from the QList:

```
QList<QString> shapes {  "Triangle", "Circle", "Trapeze", "Square", "Rectangle", "Diamond" };
```

with random int values in the neighboring cell.

Table can contain all "shapes" or only a part of it (like in the example).

I try to create separate file for each shape form the table and write down corresponding int values to them.
To achieve this I wrote something like that:

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> ItemList 
/.../
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<columns; ++i)
    {
        foreach(QString itm, shapes )
        {
            ItemList = ui->tableWidget->findItems(itm, Qt::MatchExactly); 
            QFile mFile(itm + ".txt");

            if(mFile.open(QFile::ReadWrite))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < ItemList.count(); ++i)
                {
                    int rowNR = ItemList.at(i)->row();
                    int columnNR = ItemList.at(i)->column();
                    out << "Values = " << ui->tableWidget->item(rowNR, columnNR+1)->text() << endl;
                }
            }   
        }
            mFile.flush();
            mFile.close();
    }
}
```

Files are created for every item from the QList – if the shape from the QList is not in the table, an empty file is created.

How to create files only on the basis of available names in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this.

```
QList<QTableWidgetItem *> ItemList 
/.../

for(QString str : Shapes){
    ItemList = ui->tableWidget->findItems(itm, Qt::MatchExactly); // Get the matching list

    if(ItemList.isEmpty(){
        continue; // If shape does not exist in table skip the iteration
    }

    QFile mFile(str + ".txt");
    if(!mFile.open(QFile::ReadWrite){
        return; // This should not happen ; this is error
    }

    for(QTableWidgetItem *item : ItemList){
        int row = item->row(); 
        int col = item->column()+1; // since it is neighboring cell
        QString Value = ui->tableWidget->item(row,col)->text();
        mFile.write(Value.toUtf8()); // You can change the way in which values are written
    }

    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I figure it out literally just before your answer, but your solution is much clearer and faster in execution, thanks!.